# JavaScript not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So, I stole the script off the internet. Basically, it's supposed to resize an iframe to fit its content.

```
function sizeIFrame()
{
    var helpFrame = jQuery("#elastic");
    var innerDoc = (helpFrame.get(0).contentDocument) ? helpFrame.get(0).contentDocument : helpFrame.get(0).contentWindow.document;
    helpFrame.height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 35);
}
```

It doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer, though! The iframe source is on the same server, so that shouldn't be the problem. Any idea what's wrong? The iframe ID is `#elastic`. I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, and it works in all three of them just like it's supposed to.

---

**EDIT**

I decided to just replace the script with another, more hefty jQuery solution. While it's not as lightweight as I was hoping, it appears to work.

See: http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by simply replacing my solution with this larger jQuery solution. Though bigger, it works like a charm!

http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing